# How do i check/validate existing file with my requirement in python

Tags: python, file

Suppose I have a file named abc.txt with contents FirstName, Last name, Age, gender

```
Jack, Hugman, 22, M
Joe, Zareil, 32, M
Ashely, Timberlake, 28, F
```

Now my requirement is this that I only need FirstName, LastName, and age only. So how do i validate/check my requirement with a file. These three field i would be using in my class objects

```
class A:

def __init__(self, fname, lname, age):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.age = age

fp = open("abc","r")

for lines in fp:
    temp = lines.split(",")
    print temp
```

this is what uptil  i have done. what should i do to check/validate?

Comment: 1.  What do you need to check?  You have the fields in `temp`.  2.  Validate what against what?

Comment: validate that i need only three fields in my requirement against the existing file bc.txt

Comment: My requirement is of three field and there are four field in a file. How should i check that ?

Comment: Have you looked at the CSV parser module?

Comment: You can check the number of elements in a list using `len()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split like this

```
for lines in fp:
    temp = lines.split(",")[:-1]
    print temp
```

Comment: My requirement is of three field and there are four field in a file. How should i check that ?

Comment: you do `if len(temp) < 4:` ;

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is using exceptions: Basically specify what you expect from the file, parse it assuming that everything is in there. If an assertion triggers something was off.

For example you could do:

```
a = A(temp[0], temp[1], int(temp[2])
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive ?? I am just above newbie

Comment: This should actually be valid code. It doesn't do any checks itself, but if there are less than 3 element, you'll hit an IndexError. If the 3rd argument can't be cast to int you'll get a ValueError. You could also catch those things manually if you like and handle them explicitly.

Comment: If there must be four field, you can add `assert len(temp) == 4`

Comment: @GajGaj dornhege means, once you make the split you do, a = A(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2])

Comment: @dornhege you should drop "int(temp[2]) for "temp[2]" shouldnt you ?

Comment: No, this will convert the third value into an int instead of storing it as a string. As a side effect it will also verify that it is indeed an int representation and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore the fourth field.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, age):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return "fname={}, lname={}, age={}".format(self.fname, self.lname, self.age)

with open("abc.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        fname, lname, age = [g.strip() for g in line.split(",")[:-1]]
        a = A(fname, lname, age)
        print(a)
```

Result:

```
fname=Jack, lname=Hugman, age=22
fname=Joe, lname=Zareil, age=32
fname=Ashely, lname=Timberlake, age=28
```

If your want to use only those lines with *exactly* three fields, do this:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = [g.strip() for g in line.split(",")]
        if len(fields) == 3:
            a = A(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2])
            print(a)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'A' is not defined

Comment: `A` *is*  defined at `class A`.